# Error 42601 Inner join

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I am using Postgres 9.6 and pgadmin 4.2 version.
I am getting error 42601 when executing the below query. can someone help in resolving the issues

Select EmpID, Name, address, Dept from Employee, Deptarment where Employee.EmpID = Deptarment.EmpID

Comment: You could check the spelling: I'm sure Deptarment should be Department.

Comment: Error 42601 is `SYNTAX ERROR`. See [errcodes-appendix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/errcodes-appendix.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose error **42601** is **Syntax error**
And it seems that you happen to spell your table name wrong.

It would be better if you post the
Create statement of table.

Although, it looks like that you have misspelled the table **department** in that query.
It is always recommended to use alias in such case.

Try executing that statement by replacing Deptarment by **Department**

or you can use an Alias for the same
as
Select EmpID, Name, address, Dept from Employee as e, Department as d where e.EmpID = d.EmpID

*(Assuming that you misspelled the Table Department in your Database)*

Comment: It could be a typo mistake when i wrote this question but not in the actual query and i have tried all alias combination as well, it didnt work out

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, need to put column names and tablenames under double quotes and then it works perfectly